# Transformations LiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata

What am I doing wrong? I am not getting conversions. I'm trying to convert the timestamp to a specific format in the ViewModel. I still get a timestamp on the output.

```
private var liveData: LiveData<List<Rule>>

init {
        liveData = repository.getData(collectionName, orderByField, orderByDirection)
    }

fun getData(): LiveData<List<Rule>> {
        Transformations.map(liveData) {list ->
            list.map {item ->
                item.createTimestamp = utilities.covertTimestampToDate(item.createTimestamp.toLong())
                item.updateTimestamp = utilities.covertTimestampToDate(item.updateTimestamp.toLong())
            }
        }
        return liveData
    }
```

Tried it like this:

```
fun getData(): LiveData<List<Rule>>
            = Transformations.map(liveData) {list ->
                var newList = emptyList<Rule>()
                list.map {item ->
                    item.createTimestamp = utilities.covertTimestampToDate(item.createTimestamp.toLong())
                    item.updateTimestamp = utilities.covertTimestampToDate(item.updateTimestamp.toLong())
                }
                newList = list
                return@map newList
            }
```

Tried it like this:

```
fun getData(): LiveData<List<Rule>>
            = Transformations.map(liveData) {list ->
                val newList = ArrayList<Rule>()
                list.map {item ->
                    item.createTimestamp = utilities.covertTimestampToDate(item.createTimestamp.toLong())
                    item.updateTimestamp = utilities.covertTimestampToDate(item.updateTimestamp.toLong())
                    newList.add(item)
                }
                return@map newList
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

change livedata to mutablelivedata and set the value

```
private var liveData: MutableLiveData<List<Rule>>

init {

liveData.value  = repository.getData(collectionName, orderByField, orderByDirection)
  
}
```

return transformed live data

```
fun getData(): LiveData<List<Rule>> {
          return  Transformations.map(liveData) {list ->
                list.map {item ->
                    item.createTimestamp = utilities.covertTimestampToDate(item.createTimestamp.toLong())
                    item.updateTimestamp = utilities.covertTimestampToDate(item.updateTimestamp.toLong())
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: The repository returns LiveData, so "liveData.value = ..." is not suitable in this case. I think it is necessary to change liveData to MutableLiveData and carry out the transformation at initialization to avoid re-transformation when changing the configuration (screen rotation). The problen is if I get null on transformation on initialion. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I didn't see it was LiveData. I updated my answer and changed it to MutableLiveData. Transformation will only be triggered when you set the value of MutableLiveData. So transformation won't happen on configuration change.